# Grid settings cause 'Resise layout' to not function properly

Tags: qgis, layouts, font

Recently the company I work at has made the transition from QGIS 3.10 to 3.28 (the update was long overdue) but now I continue to run into a minor, if not irritating snag.

In QGIS3.10, activating the grids to draw up coordinates along the borders of the map window, did not interfere with the Resize layout function (in the Layout Tab -> resize layout to content).
However, in QGIS3.28 I can't, for the life of me, get the resizing to work. It keeps adding "extra space" around the map window, as if there is some sort of invisible padding or buffer around the coordinates (see picture below).

[image: Screenshot showing partial map window with a white buffer around the coordinate grid]

These are the settings I used for the grid properties:
[image: Grid Properties screenshot 1]

[image: Grid Properties screenshot 2]

Does anyone know *why* this happens and what can be done to counteract this?

Comment: When you say "the Resize layout function", do you mean the button under Resize Layout to Content, in the Layout tab? Or something else?

Comment: I mean the resize layout button in the Layout tab. Apologies for that being unclear, I'll edit it in the main post to clarify. (this is the first time posting something to this forum so it's good to know that I need to clarify more)

Comment: It seem to be a QGIS bug where QGIS act as if the vertical coordinate are still horizontal and set the size based on the horizontal coordinate length (if you change the setting from vertical ascending to horizontal you will see that there are no more "padding", if you change back and resize the size won't change). I don't think there is anything on your side you can do but report the problem (see here https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html) and hope a for a fix...

Comment: yeah that is a good call, I'll make sure to report it at least and hopefully it can get fixed!

Comment: adding on to the previous comment: when turning the already horizontally drawn coordinates off, the resizing of the layout works properly again as well. As such it's not just the vertically ascending coordinate labels that cause the problem. It's all of them